# 64-bit NS_OPTIONS bitmask

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, enums, bitmask

## Context

I'm using the `NS_OPTIONS` macro to create a bitmask. I've assigned it a type of `NSInteger` and since I'm building on a 64-bit platform, that should give me a total of 63 "slots" to work with (64 bits less one bit for signed-ness).

Here is the enumeration:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, LPSVGOPlugin) {
    LPSVGOPluginNone                            = 0,
    LPSVGOPluginCleanupAttrs                    = 1 << 0,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveDoctype                   = 1 << 1,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveXMLProcInst               = 1 << 2,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveComments                  = 1 << 3,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveMetadata                  = 1 << 4,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveTitle                     = 1 << 5,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveDesc                      = 1 << 6,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveUselessDefs               = 1 << 7,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveEditorsNSData             = 1 << 8,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyAttrs                = 1 << 9,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveHiddenElems               = 1 << 10,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyText                 = 1 << 11,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyContainers           = 1 << 12,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveViewBox                   = 1 << 13,
    LPSVGOPluginCleanupEnableBackground         = 1 << 14,
    LPSVGOPluginMinifyStyles                    = 1 << 15,
    LPSVGOPluginConvertStyleToAttrs             = 1 << 16,
    LPSVGOPluginConvertColors                   = 1 << 17,
    LPSVGOPluginConvertPathData                 = 1 << 18,
    LPSVGOPluginConvertTransform                = 1 << 19,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveUnknownsAndDefaults       = 1 << 20,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveNonInheritableGroupAttrs  = 1 << 21,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveUselessStrokeAndFill      = 1 << 22,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveUnusedNS                  = 1 << 23,
    LPSVGOPluginCleanupIDs                      = 1 << 24,
    LPSVGOPluginCleanupNumericValues            = 1 << 25,
    LPSVGOPluginMoveElemsAttrsToGroup           = 1 << 26,
    LPSVGOPluginMoveGroupAttrsToElems           = 1 << 27,
    LPSVGOPluginCollapseGroups                  = 1 << 28,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveRasterImages              = 1 << 29,
    LPSVGOPluginMergePaths                      = 1 << 30,
    LPSVGOPluginConvertShapeToPath              = 1 << 31,
    LPSVGOPluginSortAttrs                       = 1 << 32,
    LPSVGOPluginTransformsWithOnePath           = 1 << 33,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveDimensions                = 1 << 34,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveAttrs                     = 1 << 35,
    LPSVGOPluginAddClassesToSVGElement          = 1 << 36,
    LPSVGOPluginRemoveStyleElement              = 1 << 37
};
```

The top value is left-shifted 37 bits, which is well below the 63 bits I should have available.

---

## The Problem

I create a mask from that enumeration, like this:

```
LPSVGOPlugin defaultPluginMask = LPSVGOPluginNone;
        defaultPluginMask = (LPSVGOPluginCleanupAttrs
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveDoctype
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveXMLProcInst
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveComments
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveMetadata
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveDesc
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveUselessDefs
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveEditorsNSData
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyAttrs
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveHiddenElems
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyText
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveEmptyContainers
                               |LPSVGOPluginCleanupEnableBackground
                               |LPSVGOPluginMinifyStyles
                               |LPSVGOPluginConvertStyleToAttrs
                               |LPSVGOPluginConvertColors
                               |LPSVGOPluginConvertPathData
                               |LPSVGOPluginConvertTransform
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveUnknownsAndDefaults
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveNonInheritableGroupAttrs
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveUselessStrokeAndFill
                               |LPSVGOPluginRemoveUnusedNS
                               |LPSVGOPluginCleanupIDs
                               |LPSVGOPluginCleanupNumericValues
                               |LPSVGOPluginMoveElemsAttrsToGroup
                               |LPSVGOPluginMoveGroupAttrsToElems
                               |LPSVGOPluginCollapseGroups
                               |LPSVGOPluginMergePaths
                               |LPSVGOPluginConvertShapeToPath
                               );
```

When I log the value of `defaultPluginMask` using this:

```
NSLog(@"maskValue: %li", (long)defaultPluginMask);
```

The result is -536879137. As soon as I remove that last mask addition (`LPSVGOPluginConvertShapeToPath`) from the mask, I get a positive value: 1610604511

Critically, `LPSVGOPluginConvertShapeToPath` is left-shifted 31 bits, which would be the maximum bit position in a 32-bit NSInteger. But if I use `sizeof()` to log the size of `defaultPluginMask`, it reports it as 8 bytes, which means it should be 64 bits.

I'm a bit (ha!) confused. Have I made a basic error I'm not seeing?

Comment: When shifting with 32 or more bits, use `1ULL << 32`

Comment: That did it! Thanks very much. If you'll write that up as an official answer and add a bit of background on why the ULL is necessary (I looked it up, but future people who look at this thread would benefit from a quick explanation), I'll mark that as the answer.

Comment: Use `stdint.h` types and macros. Also use `inttypes.h` `printf` conversion specifiers. `%li` takes a `long` which is not guaranteed to have more than 32 bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `long` data type, C standard specifies that the minimum range is required to be from `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, i.e. using `32 bits`, including the sign bit.

Even if compiling for a `64 bits` platform, it is not guaranteed that a `long` variable will be represented on `64 bits`. To ensure that it will have minimum `64 bits` of storage, `long long` should be used. As @Olaf recommended, to precisely specify the storage size, `stdint.h` types could be used (e.g. `int64_t`).

But the observations above doesn't seem to be the source of the issue in your case (if `NSInteger` and `long` sizes are >= 8 bytes).

The issue is that the value to be shifted `1` is an integer literal that fits in 32 bits and will be stored as such (if it wouldn't fit in 32 bits, e.g. 5 billions, it would be stored on 64 bits). And `1 << 31` will be a signed 32 bit integer, with 1 exactly on the sign position, so a negative number. And if this is assigned later to a 64 bit signed integer variable, the sign bit will be extended (two's complement representation).

This can be seen from the values observed in your case, which are represented in hexadecimal on 64 bits as:

```
 -536879137  =>  ffffffffdfffdfdf   - when 1 << 31 is present
 1610604511  =>          5fffdfdf   - when 1 << 31 is removed
```

Below I've done a small experiment to see what happens near this "border" (it should be noted that values obtained from `1 << 32` and `1 << 33` are undefined behaviour - shifting over the storage size, which on other platforms may happen to give the same results as `1 << 0` and `1 << 1` ).

```
printf("%d %d %d %d\n", sizeof(int), sizeof(long), sizeof(long long), sizeof(void*)); 
// Prints: 4 4 8 8, running on an Windows 64-bit, compiled with gcc from MinGW
long long a[9] = {
    1   << 30, //  1073741824         40000000
    1LL << 30, //  1073741824         40000000
    1   << 31, // -2147483648 ffffffff80000000
    1LL << 31, //  2147483648         80000000
    1   << 32, //           0                0
    1LL << 32, //  4294967296        100000000
    1   << 33, //           0                0
    1LL << 33, //  8589934592        200000000
    5000000000,//  5000000000        12a05f200
};
// Prints of this loop are in the comments above
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    printf("%12lli %16llx\n", a[i], a[i]);
```

**Solution:** If an integer literal is intended to be directly used in operations whose results won't fit in the storage size of that literal, it have to be suffixed with:

- `u`/`U` for `unsigned` (if needed)
- `l`/`L` for `long`
- `ll`/`LL` for `long long`

The issue in the question may be solved by applying the `LL` suffix to these elements:

```
LPSVGOPluginConvertShapeToPath              = 1LL << 31,
LPSVGOPluginSortAttrs                       = 1LL << 32,
LPSVGOPluginTransformsWithOnePath           = 1LL << 33,
LPSVGOPluginRemoveDimensions                = 1LL << 34,
LPSVGOPluginRemoveAttrs                     = 1LL << 35,
LPSVGOPluginAddClassesToSVGElement          = 1LL << 36,
LPSVGOPluginRemoveStyleElement              = 1LL << 37
```