# NS_OPTIONS with more than 8 values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use NS_OPTIONS in next case:

```objc
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, FZAnimalType) {
    FZAnimalTypeNone = 0,
    FZAnimalTypeBear = 1 << 0,
    FZAnimalTypeFox = 1 << 1,
    FZAnimalTypeWolf = 1 << 2,
    FZAnimalTypeTiger = 1 << 3,
    FZAnimalTypeLion = 1 << 4,
    FZAnimalTypeRabbit = 1 << 5,
    FZAnimalTypeGoat = 1 << 6,
    FZAnimalTypeParrot = 1 << 7,
    FZAnimalTypeDog = 1 << 8,
    FZAnimalTypeCat = 1 << 9,
    FZAnimalTypeSheep = 1 << 10,
    FZAnimalTypeEagle = 1 << 11 
};
```

And I have a warnings:

> Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned int' to 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char')

on last 4 lines in following code:

```objc
zoo.hasBear = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeBear;
zoo.hasFox = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeFox;
zoo.hasWolf = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeWolf;
zoo.hasTiger = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeTiger;
zoo.hasLion = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeLion;
zoo.hasRabbit = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeRabbit;
zoo.hasGoat = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeGoat;
zoo.hasParrot = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeParrot;
zoo.hasDog = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeDog;
zoo.hasCat = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeCat;
zoo.hasSheep = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeSheep;
zoo.hasEagle = registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeEagle;
```

And properties hasDog/hasCat/hasSheep/hasEagle - always NO.
Solution in this post: [64-bit NS_OPTIONS bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904321/64-bit-ns-options-bitmask) didn't help me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should check the bits by doing `zoo.hasEagle = (registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeEagle) == FZAnimalTypeEagle`

Comment: Post the header code that defines your zoo and registry structures.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the comment, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that an expression such as `registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeBear` does not result in a `BOOL`. It is still an `NSUInteger`. If the value of the integer is too large for the `BOOL` type, you get the warning.

You need to change your result to be an actual `BOOL`. Something like the following would work:

```
zoo.hasEagle = (registry.animalTypes & FZAnimalTypeEagle) != 0;
```

Make this change for all of your checks.

The other thing to keep in mind with `BOOL` is that is it best to only use `YES` and `NO` as the possible values. Try not to assign arbitrary integer values to a `BOOL` type.

Comment: Point of clarification: YES == TRUE and NO == FALSE. Those are interchangeable. But yeah, setting a BOOL to an arbitrary non-zero value as a YES/TRUE is a bad idea, and can cause very strange bugs. (`aBool = 6`. `if (aBOOL)` evaluates as true, but `if (aBool == YES)` evaluates as false.

Comment: @DuncanC which is why a `BOOL` should never be compared against `YES` or `NO`. Just do `if (aBool)` or `if (!aBool)`.